# Computers on wireless subnet not registering on DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a standard windows domain. I have a group of wireless clients that are on the domain but on a wireless network on my SonicWALL firewall and get DHCP from there. They have my LAN DNS servers for DNS and can access all LAN resources just fine. There is no traffic blocked by the firewall between the LAN and WLAN. I also added the wireless subnet under sites-and services just to see if that would help, it didn't. I cannot resolve the names of the computers on the WLAN from the LAN. The computers are not registered in DNS. I am sure I am missing something basic and would be grateful to anyone who could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are these computers joined to the domain? What is the zone update settings security set to?

Comment: All of the wireless computers are on the same domain as the wired and have no problem accessing resources on he doamin but they are not in DNS. Dynamic updates are set to "secure only" allow zone transfers is not checked, I am not sure if that is the answer to your question.